# Proofs that $\zeta(4) = \frac{\pi^4}{90}$ with Wallis-like intergals

Tags: calculus

In *Proof #9, Matsuoka*, [pg. 16](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Ebwsulliv/MathGradTalkZeta2.pdf) in the seminar notes by Brendan W. Sullivan, the Wallis-like integral below is used to prove $\displaystyle \zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

> $$J_n = \int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 x^2 \cos^nx dx $$

Are there proofs that $\displaystyle \zeta(4) = \frac{\pi^4}{90}$ with similar integrals?

(I mean, can we show $\displaystyle \zeta(4) = \frac{\pi^4}{90}$ with $\displaystyle K_n = \int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 x^4 \cos^nx dx $ or somthing like that?)